# Six buttons mouse do not work in a virtualized environment

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, virtualization, proxmox

I have a six buttons mouse, in this has back and forward buttons, this does not work on a virtualized Proxmox environment.

Environment: Proxmox 7
Image: Ubuntu 22
Mouse: Logi MX Keys

Comment: You'll need to use USB passthrough to get the mouse directly recognized in the VM.  Try "usb passthrough proxmox" on your search engine and you'll get the steps needed.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse actions in a virtual environment (virtual machine) are provided by the virtual app and provide basic mouse functions.

Some additional mouse functions are provided by Guest extensions or tools installed in the Guest machine.

If your particular mouse is not supported, you will need to use a mouse that is supported.